# Подключение БД Django к приложению (python)

Tags: python, django, база-данных

Пожалуйста, помогите выполнить задание: нужно написать код , который будет считывать данные с формы (имя и номер телефона) и отправлять в БД Django, с которой впоследствии нужно будет сравнить данные с парсера (если номер телефона есть в базе CRM, пропускаем, если нет — добавляем контакт). Прошу объяснить, как связать БД и django приложение с готовой html формой :)

main/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls'))

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('main',  views.main),

]
```

app/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def main(request):
    return render(request, 'app/main.html')
```

main.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Главная страница</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Страница ввода контакта</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" class="form-control"><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Номер телефона" class="form-control"><br>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>

</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Вы собес на кого проходите?

Comment: На самом деле сейчас просто тренюсь, пишу код по реальным тестовым заданиям, так планирую работать python разработчиком, что логично :) стараюсь, практикуюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно создать класс для обработки  формы.

Здесь мы наследуемся от `CreateView`, указываем модель, с которой работаем. Модель должна быть создана заранее, указываем поля, которые обрабатываем, `success_url` в случае успеха переведет на нужную страницу, `template_name` указываете свой.

```
class CreateComment(CreateView):
    model = Comments
    fields = ['user', 'post', 'body']
    template_name = 'mysite/CreateComment.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('themes')
```

Также нужно принимать пользователя, который перейдет по ссылке создания,
вот пример:

```
path('posts/post_edit/create_comment/', CreateComment.as_view(), name='create_comment'),
```

Теперь, при переходе на `127.0.0.0:8000/posts/post_edit/create_comment`, будет вызываться шаблон создания комментария, и все будет обрабатываться во вьюхе выше.